# How to use pacemaker to use Virtual/Floating IP address?

Tags: high-availability, pacemaker, virtual-ip-address

I have two VMs running on 65 subnet and I want to use my management subnet 64 to redirect the traffic on either of the VM on 65 subnet.

I am trying to build an HA system.

Do I need three VM setup on 65 subnets to maintain quorem and pacemaker will run on which VM?